# Разная скорость анимации при hover для одного элемента

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Столкнулся с одной не очень приятной проблемой. Необходимо сделать для элемента несколько свойств при ховере с разным `animation-duration`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А можно более конкретный пример, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, без проблем. Перечесляете разные изменения в `transition` через запятую. К примеру, анимация изменения цвета фона выполняется за 0,5 секунды, изменение высоты за 2 секунды.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, height 2s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```